# TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'getSelected' in Joomla ChronoForm

Tags: javascript, forms, joomla, mootools

I'm getting this JS error on my code:

error: `TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'getSelected'`

code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '0');
$('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '0');
$('recipe').addEvent('change', function() {
var opt;
opt = this.getSelected().getProperty('data-serial').toString();
if ( opt.length > 0 ) {
  $('modelnumber').value = opt;
  $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '1');
  $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '1');
} else {
  $('modelnumber').value = '';
  $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '0');
  $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '0');
}
});
});
```

Can somebody please tell me what I did wrong? I tried everything already.
Thank you

Comment: I added data-serial attributes to the options with serial numbers like this

'code' <option id="hide_none" value="blablabla" data-serial='12345' > 'code'

where "hide_me1" is the container for an input.

This hides the input when the page loads, then looks for a data-serial value when the drop-down changes. if it finds a value then it sets the value and displays the input, otherwise it clears any set value and hides the input.

.getSelected it's Mootools, it gets the selected option from dropdown.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, as those functions does'nt really look like plain javascript or jQuery methods ?

Comment: Hide an input when some select options are selected, and show the input when others are selected

Comment: And where did those strange looking selectors and functions come from? I'm assuming this is some specific code for Joomla, as it's certainly not jQuery ?

Comment: jQuery version would look like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Qxh/), and I'm assuming those are ID's of the elements ?

Comment: This is mootools, not jquery. This code works. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9G3by/1/) with a basic working version of what I assume your HTML looks like.

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand why it gives me the "TypeError" error...?

Comment: Try changing `this.getSelected()` to `$(this.id).getSelected()`. That should get it working at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is as it seems to me the code works on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9G3by/2/).

It seems that in your case `this` isn't being wrapped by MooTools. I would try changing `this.getSelected` to `$(this.id).getSelected()` and seeing if that works.

Comment: do you have multiple libraries installed or just mootools? If multiple, try `document.id(this.id).getSelected()`.

Comment: You can see the form here: http://goo.gl/6DZja , you will see the select in "Product Information" block.

Comment: I assume it's because of my version of Mootools 1.1.2... but if I change the version to 2.5 I have another TypeError in the same form but not related to this code.. :(

Comment: so I was wondering maybe something can be done with the version of Mootools that I have?

Comment: I updated Mootools to 1.2.5 and change like you said from Element.extend to Element.implement and it workss :))) Thank you